# Read metadata from a MPEG file in encoded domain

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I'm trying to extract information from an MPEG video in an encoded domain. I use

```
avformat_open_input(&s, url, NULL, &options)
```

to read the data packet. Is there a possible way of reading meta data from the file before decoding?

I can get information such as size and duration which are available in AVPacket structure. I want to get information other than that.

Comment: Metadata like what? Global (per-stream) metadata can be found with `avformat_find_stream_info`; just be aware it can actually decode several frames of each elementary stream in the file in order to get that metadata.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that by decoding the header, it is possible to take much information about the video.